# Can't get array key to work with Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-php

```
  /**
  * @SWG\POST(
  *   path="/visa-entry/calculate",
  *   operationId="visaEntryCalculate",
  *   tags={"Visa Entry"},
  *   summary="Calculate the price for an array of visa entries",
  *   description="Calculate the price for an array of visa entries",
  *
  *   @SWG\Parameter(
  *     name="entries",
  *     in="body",
  *     description="Visa Entry IDs to calculate to total price",
  *     required=true,
  *     @SWG\Schema(
  *       type="array",
  *       @SWG\Items(type="number")
  *     ),
  *     collectionFormat="multi"
  *   ),
  *
  *   @SWG\Response(
  *     response=200,
  *     description="OK"
  *   ),
  *
  *   @SWG\Response(
  *     response=400,
  *     description="Bad request"
  *   ),
  * )
  *
  * Calculates a visa entry
  */
```

What I'm trying to do is to receive an Array of numbers with the key `entries`.

```
entries: [1, 2, 3]
```

This docblock renders the following CURL.

```
curl -X POST "app.test/visa-entry/calculate" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-CSRF-TOKEN: " -d "[0]"
```

How can I get it to send the array with the key `entries`?

Comment: 1) By "docblock" do you mean Swagger UI? Can you post an image? 2) Do you need to post as JSON `{"entries": [1, 2, 3] }` or as form data `entries=1,2,3`?

Comment: 1) It's the code I posted. Annotation/docblock, whatever you call it. 2) JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the client to post the array directly in the request-body, but with a key, you'll need to specify the `in=body` parameter as `type="object"` and define the array as a property of that schema.

Like this:

```
/**
 * @SWG\POST(
 *   path="/visa-entry/calculate",
 *   operationId="visaEntryCalculate",
 *   tags={"Visa Entry"},
 *   summary="Calculate the price for an array of visa entries",
 *   description="Calculate the price for an array of visa entries",
 *
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *     in="body",
 *     name="json",
 *     description="Visa Entry IDs to calculate to total price",
 *     required=true,
 *     @SWG\Schema(
 *       type="object",
 *       @SWG\Property(
 *         property="entries",
 *         type="array",
 *         @SWG\Items(type="number")
 *       )
 *     ),
 *     collectionFormat="multi"
 *   ),
 *
 *   @SWG\Response(
 *     response=200,
 *     description="OK"
 *   ),
 *
 *   @SWG\Response(
 *     response=400,
 *     description="Bad request"
 *   ),
 * )
 *
 * Calculates a visa entry
 */
```

Comment: Is there any way to initialize array as [1, 2, 3]? Right now it is [0].

Comment: property example causes error, `example=[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: You'll need to use doctrine's array notation {1,2,3} https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/guide/annotations.html#arrays-and-objects